# Problems with jQuery UI accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having problems with jQuery UI's accordion widget. On the site below, after the initial page loads click on Today. The Accordion is loaded via Ajax.

http://opencalendars.com/alpha/v0.9.1/event.php

When I use a function to load that tab directly on start it seems to work.

http://opencalendars.com/alpha/v0.9.1/event.php?p=2

Here are the options I'm using...

```
$( ".accordion" ).accordion({'fillSpace': true,
'clearStyle': true });
```

Any idea what the problem is here?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem seems to be here:

```
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ selected: $.getUrlVar('p'), cache: true, spinner: 'Retrieving data...',fx: { opacity: 'toggle' }  }
```

Since you are getting the value of `selected` from the URL, it is undefined and defaulting to 0.  Try defaulting it to 1:

```
var selectedTab = $.getUrlVar('p') || 1;
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ selected: selectedTab, cache:...
```

Comment: I have made the update to the live site using 0 instead of 1. Since 0 is the first page in this case.

However it doesn't fix the accordion issue.

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question.  Is your problem that it is smaller when you don't go to `?p=2`?

Comment: Yes the jQuery accordion it doesn't show all of the content contained within it. The problem doesn't occur when using ?p=2

Answer (score 2):

Instantiate the accordions before the tabs. The problem is that when you ask it to build the accordions they have already been "hidden" by the tabs, so the accordions are not able to properly calculate a height. They mistakenly believe that they have no content.

[jsFiddle of Tabs before Accordions](http://jsfiddle.net/KnEAm/)

[jsFiddle of Accordions before Tabs but with 'filSpace':true](http://jsfiddle.net/KnEAm/2/)

[jsFiddle of Accordions before Tabs](http://jsfiddle.net/KnEAm/1/) **WINNAR**

Notice that the first example has the same problem you do. Just flip your two lines

```
$( ".accordion" ).accordion({clearStyle: true  });
$( "#tabs" ).tabs({ selected: selectedTab, cache: true, spinner: 'Retrieving data...',fx: { opacity: 'toggle' }  }
        ).find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).sortable({ axis: "x" });
```

Comment: I was sure this would fix the problem. But the update to the live version had no effect.

Comment: why did you add 'fillSpace': true ? That tells an accordion set to completely fill it's parent. Only your parent has no size.

Comment: Someone else had suggested adding 'fillSpace': true . I have removed it and it doesn't work either way.

Answer (score 0):

Add the option

```
autoHeight: false
```